# Retrieve Likes/dislikes on idea comments

Tags: ideas

I am writing a custom `Visualforce Page` for `Ideas`.

I want to retrieve which user liked or disliked the comments on idea.
I could retrieve the votes(promote or demote) on ideas from `Vote` object, aswell as retrieve comments for idea posted by user from `IdeaComment` object.

But could not do the same with like/dislike i.e. which user liked or disliked comment.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the child relationships, I see this one that seems to be what you are looking for:

> Schema.ChildRelationship[
>           **getChildSObject=Vote;**
>           getField=ParentId;
>           getJunctionIdListNames=();
>           getRelationshipName=Votes;
>           isCascadeDelete=true;
>           isDeprecatedAndHidden=false;
>           isRestrictedDelete=false;
>       ]

So the `sObjectType` you seek is **`Vote`**. You can investigate child relationships yourself as follows:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.IdeaComment.getChildRelationships())
    system.debug(relation);
```